# Error 400 : redirect_uri_mismatch JavaScript origin with google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I want to build a web app and it should be deployed as me because i don't want force users to accept som risky authorisation but at the same time i need to know their adress email.

thats why i thought about google login API when i tried to run it i got this error message.

[image: Error message while login in google API]

so i tried to put the url in the redirect url in google developper console but i got this error

[image: Error message while adding url in google console]

can somebody help me please ?

i use this code to interact with google API

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
        content="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

i tried to put origin url on both side but i got:

[image]

thank you in advanced

Comment: In the future you should set your browser to English so that your images can be read.

Comment: yes you are right i've done now thank you.

Comment: See [#41](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170740549#comment41) for server side flow

Comment: Thank you very much man u saved my life after 1 day of trying to understand the documentation i finally made it !!!!!